# Complex integral over two differents closed path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

The first integral that I want to calculate is: $$\int_{|z-2|=5}\frac{z^3 +3}{z^2+1}\,dz$$

And the second is $$\int_{|z|=\frac{1}{2}}\frac{z^3 +3}{z^2+1}\,dz$$

The denominator can be factored into $(z+i)(z−i)$. As $z_0=i$ and  $z_1=-i$ are inside the path $|z−2|=5$ I can't use Cauchy and I don't know how to solve those integrals with other method.

In the second case $z_0$ and $z_1$ aren't inside $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ so I can to use Cauchy

Comment: Just use the Cauchy Residue Theorem, right? For each simple pole $z_k$ inside the region, find $2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f,z_k)$ and then add those up. The $z_k$ to be included will depend on what the region is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cauchy's Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem): if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain $\Omega$ except at a number of poles then the integral of $f$ along a closed contour in $\Omega$ that circulates the poles just once is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at the poles lying inside the contour.  The *residue* at a pole $z_0$ is the the coefficient to the term $1/(z-z_0)$ in the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $z_0$.

In your first integral, the contour includes two poles at $z = \pm i$.

Writing $$\frac{z^3+3}{z^2+1} = z + \frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{3i-1}{z+i}-\frac{3i+1}{z-i} \Bigg)$$
you can see the residues at the two poles.  At $z=-i$ it is therefore $\frac{1}{2}(3i-1)$ and that at $z=i$ is $-\frac{1}{2}(3i+1)$.  Now apply the theorem, noting that the sum of the two residues is $-1$, to obtain,
$$\int_{|z-2|=5} \frac{z^3+3}{z^2+1} dz = -2\pi i. $$

For the second integral, neither pole lies inside the contour and therefore the same theorem implies the integral will be zero.